# How do I decode a DRF response object's content to a Python String?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following route in Django Rest Framework:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MainViewset(ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def alive(self, request):
        return Response("API is Alive", 200)
```

I have a Django test that calls this API route, expecting the JSON string:

```
def test_base_route(self):
    c = Client()
    response = c.get('/budget/alive')
    self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 200)
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode("UTF-8"), "API is Alive")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    def test_base_route(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.get('/budget/alive')
        self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 200)
>       self.assertEqual(response.content.decode("UTF-8"), "API is Alive")

E       AssertionError: '"API is Alive"' != 'API is Alive'
E       - "API is Alive"
E       ? -            -
E       + API is Alive
```

I find this strange since I decoded the string. I know it's a simple thing to trim off quotation marks, but what is the right way to serialize a single string as a response and get it back in the content of a response in DRF when sending JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.data` for this case:

```
self.assertEqual(response.data, "API is Alive")
```